# How to cancel processed order?

Tags: magento2

I have created an order and invoice is generated. After creating the invoice, the customer asked to cancel the order.

How to cancel the invoice created order.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cancel the invoice but you need to create credit memo.

Open your order, then click on credit memo and click on refund offline

Answer (score 0):

Canceling the invoice is to remove part of the history of the order.  If the order was invoiced and charged, but it would be desired to undo that, the correct process is to acknowledge that the order was invoiced, charged, and then add the additional step in the procedure that issues a credit refund to the customer.

The entire transaction and exchange of monies will be logged and referenced for more historical "paper-trail" than you may be aware of.  It would be a good idea to understanding all the transactions that were completed, then resulted in returns/refunds.  In additional to historical sales/returns data, if there is any discrepancy about the order in the future, the transaction details for each step from start to finish will be accessible as fact.

Consider that you can even track details from the payment gateway for the charge, as well as for the refund/credit, to cover your butt if the customer cannot recall the outcome or the tries to scam.